# Stutter when updating Video Texture using multiple Pixel Buffer Objects

Tags: opengl, video

I have an application that decodes a video file using FFMPEG (in a separate thread) and renders this texture using PBOs in another. All the PBO do-hickey happens in the following function:

```
void DynamicTexture::update()
{
    if(!_isDirty)
    {
        return;
    }

    /// \todo   Check to make sure that PBOs are supported
    if(_usePbo)
    {
        // In multi PBO mode, we keep swapping between the PBOs
        // We use one PBO to actually set the texture data that we will upload
        // and the other we use to update/modify. Once modification is complete,
        // we simply swap buffers

        // Unmap the PBO that was updated last so that it can be released for rendering

        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, _pboIds[_currentPboIndex]);
        glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);
        Util::GLErrorAssert();

        // bind the texture
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId);
        Util::GLErrorAssert();

        // copy pixels from PBO to texture object
        // Use offset instead of pointer.
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, _width, _height, 
                        (_channelCount==4)?GL_RGBA:GL_RGB,
                        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
        Util::GLErrorAssert();

        // Now swap the pbo index
        _currentPboIndex = (++_currentPboIndex) % _numPbos;

        // bind PBO to update pixel values
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, _pboIds[_currentPboIndex]);
        Util::GLErrorAssert();

        // map the next buffer object into client's memory
        // Note that glMapBuffer() causes sync issue.
        // If GPU is working with this buffer, glMapBuffer() will wait(stall)
        // for GPU to finish its job
        GLubyte* ptr = (GLubyte*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
        Util::GLErrorAssert();
        if(ptr)
        {
            // update data directly on the mapped buffer
            _currentBuffer = ptr;
            Util::GLErrorAssert();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unable to map PBO!");
            assert(false);
        }

        // It is good idea to release PBOs with ID 0 after use.
        // Once bound with 0, all pixel operations behave normal ways.
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
        Util::GLErrorAssert();

        // If a callback was registered, call it
        if(_renderCallback)
        {
            (*_renderCallback)(this);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureId);
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                        _width, _height, (_channelCount==4)?GL_RGBA:GL_RGB,
                        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                        &(_buffer[0]) 
                        );
        Util::GLErrorAssert();
    }

    // Reset the dirty flag after updating
    _isDirty = false;
}
```

In the decoding thread, I simply update _currentBuffer and set the _isDirty flag to true. This function is called in the render thread.

When I use a single PBO, i.e. when _numPbos=1 in the above code, then the rendering works fine without any stutter. However, when I use more than one PBO, there is a visible stutter in the video. You can find a sample of me rendering 5 videos with _numPbos=2 [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_3UZN1ZieQgX1dRTFFZemZFUDA). The more number of PBOs I use, the worse the stutter becomes.

Theoretically, the buffer that I am updating and the buffer than I am using for render are different, so there should be no glitch of this sort. I want to use double/triple buffering so as to increase rendering performance.

I am looking for some pointers/hints as to what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, if it is your problem, but after you call this:

```
 glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, _pboIds[_currentPboIndex]);
 glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER);
 Util::GLErrorAssert();
```

You are calling

```
glBindTexture
```

But you are still operating with buffer at index `_currentPboIndex`.

In my code, I have two indices - index and nextIndex

In init I set

```
index = 0;
nextIndex = 1;
```

Than my update pipeline is like this:

```
index = (index + 1) % 2;
nextIndex = (nextIndex + 1) % 2;

uint32 textureSize = sizeof(RGB) * width * height;


GL_CHECK( glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo[nextIndex]) );
GL_CHECK( glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, textureSize, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW_ARB) );
GL_CHECK( gpuDataPtr = glMapBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0, textureSize, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT) );

//update data gpuDataPtr

GL_CHECK( glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB) );

//bind texture

GL_CHECK( glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pbo[index]) ); 

GL_CHECK( glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 
            width, height, glFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0) );

GL_CHECK( glBindBufferARB(type, 0) );
```

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem. Calling glUnmapBuffer does not mean that the buffer object is no longer valid. It simply lets the driver move the buffer around in GPU memory. Its only its mapping in client space that will be invalidated.